# How/Where decision is made to choose between eager execution & graph execution for Tensorflow kernel OPs

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers, intel-mkl, eager-execution, intel-dnn

**Description :** I ran HuggingFace BERT model which uses tensorflow 2.13v with oneDNN support on intel machine and recorded its execution logs by setting TF_CPP_MAX_VLOG_LEVEL=2 & ONEDNN_VERBOSE=1 in file.

**Observation :** I have observing logs that are produced after model creation and its weight loading.
Since model.fit() always run in graph model, all tensorflow kernel OPs (onednn's mkl kernel op and non-mkl kernel ops) should run in graph mode. But i observe only for non-mkl kernel ops (like ADDV2, Mul) are executing in eager mode followed by graph mode. I dont see any mkl kernel ops(like _MklMatMul) running in eager mode.

**Questions:** I want to know the reason and file where decision making is made for which op there should be eager mode. Since model.fit() runs in graph mode, why I am seeing eager mode execution for all non-mkl ops?

**Sample Logs for model.fit() for ADDV2 kernel op:**

2023-07-31 03:48:44.632289: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:1678] Executing op AddV2 in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0  **--> executing addv2 eagerly**
After some other logs in between, I see below log:

2023-07-31 03:50:01.968512: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:841] Process node: 8127 step -4458402160563696089 {{node tf_bert_for_sequence_classification/bert/encoder/layer_._0/output/LayerNorm/batchnorm/add_1}} = AddV2[T=DT_FLOAT, _XlaHasReferenceVars=false, *device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](tf_bert_for_sequence_classification/bert/encoder/layer*.*0/output/LayerNorm/batchnorm/mul_1, tf_bert_for_sequence_classification/bert/encoder/layer*._0/output/LayerNorm/batchnorm/sub) device: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0  **--> executing addv2 in graph mode i assume**

**Expected to happen:** All kerenl ops should execute in graph mode.

Comment: This issue is more related to TensorFlow rather than Intel-MKL. We can see that this issue is now being opened and tracked with the official TensorFlow GitHub repository: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61476 by you.